# ubuntu 20.04 (never new updates)

Tags: updates

I've been using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS for some time now. However, I've recently noticed that there seem to never be any updates (using the software center, terminal or the updater). I wonder if I mis-clicked something or not. I have no idea why there are never any updates for security. My computer now has said for about two weeks that my computer is up to date.

Thank you

Comment: There were updates as recently as the 27th. Pick a mirror that works. `2020-12-27 19:15:32 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2` was the last update I got.

Comment: Thank you. I did an automatic search for the best mirror and it appears to be NY for now. I'll just go with that and see if there are updates soon. Thank you.